# Upgrading to 7.26 - Internal Server Error

Tags: 7, .htaccess, upgrading

I recently upgraded from Drupal 7.25 to 7.26 in maintenance mode.  The upgrading did not have any errors.

Now when I go to the homepage I get an Internal Server Error.

I added an echo statement to verify that bootstrap.inc was executing.

I haven't been able to log any PHP errors.

This is the first part of my .htaccess file (the other part that includes rewrites isn't allowed by Stackexchange due to links)

```
    # Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Multiviews creates problems with aliased URLs and is not needed for Drupal.
Options -Multiviews

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Force simple error message for requests for non-existent favicon.ico.
<Files favicon.ico>
  # There is no end quote below, for compatibility with Apache 1.3.
  ErrorDocument 404 "The requested file favicon.ico was not found.
</Files>

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and drupal_initialize_variables() in
# includes/bootstrap.inc for settings that can be changed at runtime.

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
  php_flag register_globals                 off
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You need to find out what the specific error is, without that we can't help. If it's not a php error then check your apache logs

Comment: It's not listed in my apache error logs (at least the one available in Cpanel).

Comment: Looks like it is stuck in maintenance mode (it didn't say this in firefox even with caching off - I needed to open a new private tab to get it). This is good news as I can try to fix it!

Comment: When I log in as the admin user it gives me a blank page.  No error message.

Comment: Watchdog log says: "Notice - Undefined index: adaptivetheme. function drupal theme_initialize() %files /home/energy/public_html/drupal/includes/theme.inc  %line 100 severity level 5"

Comment: I think the inherent cache clear barfed because of a timeout or memory error.

Comment: I ran update.php which is meant to clear the cache.  I also manually deleted the cache table contents.  Still goes blank when I login. Otherwise stuck in maintenance mode.

Comment: I have been upgrading it to a different location than the database dump.  Could this be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Always run the update script each time a module / the site is updated.

IE:  site.com/update.php

It triggers the update hooks in the modules and lets them deal with any db type changes.

After that flush the Drupal caches (admin/config/development/performance/) to clear out any old references.